# Why particles move toward a weird direction

Tags: opengl, glsl

I want to implement a particle system simulating the raining effects, the particles are expected to move along -y direction, but only some of them behave correctly, and others turns out to move in a wrong direction -x. Here is the compute shader code:

```
#version 430
layout (local_size_x = 1000) in;

struct Particle
{
        vec4 pAnds;                                             //position and size
        vec3 velocity;
        float lifespan;
        float age;
};

layout (std430, binding = 0) buffer members_in
{
        Particle particle[];
} input_data;

shared int shared_newParticles = 480 / 60;

void main()
{
        int id = int(gl_GlobalInvocationID.x);

        float timestep = 1.0 / 60.0;

        if (input_data.particle[id].lifespan > 0)
        {
                input_data.particle[id].age += timestep;

                if (input_data.particle[id].age > input_data.particle[id].lifespan)
                {
                input_data.particle[id].lifespan = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                input_data.particle[id].pAnds.y += -0.1;
                }
        }
        else if (input_data.particle[id].lifespan == 0)
        {
                if (shared_newParticles > 0)
                {
                input_data.particle[id].pAnds = vec4(input_data.particle[id].pAnds.x, 20,
                input_data.particle[id].pAnds.z, input_data.particle[id].pAnds.w);
                input_data.particle[id].lifespan = 1.0;
                input_data.particle[id].age = 0.0;

                shared_newParticles--;
                }
        }
}
```

The problem is caused by the qualifier: std430

Answer (score 1):

The code itself looks alright to me, but since you didn't post the shaders which render the particles, it is hard to diagnose the problem. My assumption is that the problem lies in your "hack" to store the position and size in a single variable. If you simply multiply this position with the Model-View-Projection-Matrix in your vertex shader, the result would be very strange. Especially the w-coordinate of the vector would pose a problem, since positions stored in a vec4 have to have a 1 at this position (they are so-called homogeneous coordinates). For normals, you would need a 0. This coordinate determines if and how the position is translated, so it would fit your problem. It would also be helpful if you could post the applied transformations to the particles.

Comment: rendering shader code is added. I have implement another particle sys with this rendering shader code and CPU calculating the particle data instead of compute shader doing that, and it worked fine. I'm not sure if there's a problem.

Comment: So, is it working now? You edited your code saying the problem was the qualifier std430. If it is not working, it would help if you could supply the data structure storing the particles. Also, you said that the rendering code "is added". Where is it?